# Receiving "NO CARRIER" error while tring to make a call using GSM modem in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gsm, at-command, modem

I want to make a call using my GSM modem. So I wrote the below program:

```
import time
import serial

recipient = "+98xxxxxxxxxx"

phone = serial.Serial("COM10",  115200, timeout=5)
try:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    phone.write(b'ATD"'+recipient.encode() +b'"\r')
    while(1):
        print(phone.readline())
    time.sleep(0.5)
finally:
    phone.close()
```

But when I run it I receive this output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
b'ATZ\r\r\n'
b'OK\r\n'
b'ATDxxxxxxxxxx\r\r\n'
b'NO CARRIER\r\n'
```

**What does this "NO CARRIER" error means?**

*Note that I can send SMS successfully.*

---

This is the program that I use to send SMS:

```
import time
import serial

recipient = "+98xxxxxxxxxx"
message = "Test"

phone = serial.Serial("COM10",  115200, timeout=5)


try:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + recipient.encode() + b'"\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(message.encode() + b"\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(bytes([26]))
    time.sleep(0.5)
finally:
    phone.close()
```

Comment: Can you post your SMS sending code?  I'm pretty sure I know what's happening

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the origin of the error :

The syntax is `ATD+98xxxxxxxxxx;` followed by terminating string. I was forgotten to put semicolon at the end after the number.

So I replace

```
phone.write(b'ATD"'+recipient.encode() +b'"\r')
```

with

```
phone.write(b'ATD"'+recipient.encode() +b';"\r')
```

And now it works fine.

---

Based on the brackets in [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Cellular%20Modules/AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r0.pdf) documents, I thought that using ";" is optional. But it seems that I was wrong.
[image]

Comment: Personally I would use: `phone.write(b'ATD"%s";\r' % recipient.encode())` as being clearer what is going on and a little more compact.

Comment: For completeness regarding the semicolon: The `ATD` command has a `L` modifier that makes the modem dial the last dialed number. So if you first start a data call with `ATD1234` then you can after that call ends give `ATDL` to set up a new data call to the same number. The not so obvious issue here is for voice calls. If you first set up a **voice call** with `ATD1234;` then just giving `ATDL` will set up a **data call** to number 1234, so the modem only reuses the number and not the type of the call. If you want to repeat a voice call you have to give `ATDL;` with a semicolon at the end.

Comment: @hlovdal thank you dear friend. May I ask you to say me what's the difference between a voice call and a data call? Can I initiate a data call using a dial up modem also, or it is for GSM modems only?

Comment: Hi nlovdal, I have "NO CARRIER" error with command ATD+39**********; . SIM is unlocked (AT+CPIN? returns READY), the signal quality is OK (AT+CSQ returns 9,3) and It's registered properly to a network (AT+COPS? returns 0,0,"vodafone IT",2). Any suggestion to fix the issue?

Comment: @aldo85ita me too getting the same error. did u found the answer ?

Comment: I have found that getting NO CARRIER could also mean that you don't have any airtime left to dial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ill tell you

Its all because of a semicolun

If you're using direct connection like me (UART, serial monitor)

Use semicolon

Ex: ATD+91xxxxxxxxxx;

This will solve NO CARRIER issue as i was able to send sms recieve sms and recieve calls
Stil persist its because of signal

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35612340)